# Unit testing Angular 2 components inside a common library NPM Package no app context

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am kind of stumped on this. I have used the Angular 2 quick start projects as a reference for unit testing Angular 2 but it seems to assume you have an app in play. In my case we have NPM packages that have Angular 2 modules in them that are shared across various projects in our organization. I would like to be able to unit test the code inside these common libraries in isolation (without them being part of an app).

I am looking for examples or a tutorial or something explaining the best approach to this, Google has not provided any help.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am doing in my Karma test something like:

**Create a mock component**

```
@Component({
       template: "",
       selector: 'mock'
})
export class MockComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Is loaduing");
  }
}
```

---

**Create a mock service**

```
class MockSomeService {
  public subscribe(){}
  public inizialize() {}
}
```

---

**Create ROUTES array**

```
export var ROUTES = [ {path:"/pathexample", component: MockComponent}]
```

---

**Create DECLARATIONS array**

```
export var DECLARATIONS:Component[] = [
  MockComponent, ExampleComponent
];
```

---

**Create PROVIDERS**

```
const CONSTANTS_PROVIDERS: Provider[] = [
  { provide: SomeService, useClass: MockSomeService }
];
```

---

**Write a test**

```
describe('Component: example', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: DECLARATIONS, providers: CONSTANTS_PROVIDERS, imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(ROUTES)] });
  });

  it('should create an instance', inject([ExampleComponent], (component: ExampleComponent) => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));

});
```

If your component is using **route.navigate** you should use **TestBed.overrideComponent** and add `template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'` to your component if not have it yet and actually create the component like this **TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);**